# How to create Certificate Request for CVC certificate as like X.509 (PKCS#10) in Java?

Tags: csr, pkcs#10

How to create Certificate Request for CVC certificate as like X.509 (PKCS#10) in Java to send as a certificates signing request to EJBCA Certificate Authority?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cert-cvc library, also open source. This is part of EJBCA and comes with sample code. You can find more information and download at the [ejbca.org](https://www.ejbca.org/download.html) site.